# How to access js object properties via html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, arrays

I have an array of objects fetched using jQuery.getJSON(). I want every one of my objects to be represented by HTML div element, so when you click the element you have access to all the properties of corresponding object. What is the best way to do it?

I wanted to do it like this:

```
$('.mydiv').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   for (i=0; i<myObjectsArray.length; i++){
     for (x in myObjectsArray[i]){
         //..and here I got confused...
     }  
   }
});
```

Is this approach any good or is there a better way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: i find it hard to understand your question/suggest some kind of solution without knowing more about the content of myObjectsArray. arranging it so it can be accessed by myObjectsArray[id] i probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can store data in the `data` property of your jQuery object
[docs here](http://api.jquery.com/data/)